# Fail to start iptables.service: 'No such file'

Tags: centos, iptables

I'm trying to directly use iptables instead of firewalld to manage firewall rules. However `systemctl start iptables` prints:

```
[root@centos-new ~]# systemctl start iptables
Failed to issue method call: Unit iptables.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

I'm running a newly installed CentOS 7 so it is hardly possible to let something important be deleted by me. What could be the possible problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`firewalld` is installed by default on CentOS7 systems. You need to disable it and install `iptables` instead. These steps should do it:

```
systemctl mask firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
yum install iptables-services
systemctl enable iptables
systemctl start iptables
```

Optionally, if you want to handle IPv6 as well:

```
systemctl enable ip6tables
systemctl start ip6tables
```